# Does traffic get discarded if a google cloud endpoint is redeployed?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Let's say for argument's sake that I have a vm instance, which is configured with an endpoint `config_id` in it's meta-data that is set to an existing working cloud endpoint.

Can someone please explain to me what happens to the incoming requests if the cloud endpoint is redeployed? Obviously, I will get an new `config_id`, but if haven't yet applied this `config_id` to the vm instance, does the traffic just get discarded?

If this is the case, what are some viable solutions to prevent service interruption for my users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traffic keeps going to the old configuration until you change the `endpoints-service-config-id` with the new `config_id`:

[image]

And then ssh into the VM instance with `gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE-NAME]` and run `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`.

In conclusion, traffic won't be discarded. It just keeps using the old config deployment. See [redeploying](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deploy-api-backend#redeploying)

Comment: Is an "/etc/init.d/nginx reload" good enough, or does it actually need to be restarted?